# <ValueError: Sheet already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'> on one machine but not on another

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm running some basic python code which generates a pandas DataFrame called df and then writes it to a pre-formatted Excel file using pandas ExcelWriter and openpyxl as its engine.

```
workbook = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = workbook['example_sheet']
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('example.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
writer.book = workbook
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}

sheet.cell(row=8, column=5).value = some.value
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='example_sheet', index=False, header=False, startrow=10, startcol=5)
```

The strange thing is that when running on my machine it works perfectly, however on my colleague's machine it throws the mentioned error:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 437, in write_cells f"Sheet '{sheet_name}' already exists and " ValueError: Sheet 'example_sheet' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.
```

I've tried working around it by explicitly setting

```
if_sheet_exists = 'replace'
```

however now (as expected) it replaces the entire sheet and destroys the formatting that was applied before. When running on my machine however it would not replace the sheet, even though the writer was set to do so.

I'm not entirely sure where to look for differences in the machines so if anyone could throw me an idea I would be very thankful.

Comment: You must assume that there are differences in things like the versions of packages between the two computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last Pandas version to behave as you expect was version 1.2.5. `pip uninstall pandas` and then `pip install pandas==1.2.5`, then it will simply append the data to your previously formatted Excel template.

YMMV.

Edit:

I believe the issue was with `openpyxl`, which you may be able to revert separately if the above solution is not feasible. You might also try `if_sheet_exists = 'overlay'` if it suits your needs.

Comment: I run into the same issue, my script returns this error since pandas has been updated. How do you get the 'old' behaviour with the new version (I use 1.3.5)? I don't see any difference in the doc for the 2 versions. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the issue was with openpyxl, which you may be able to revert separately if the above solution is not feasible. You might also try ```if_sheet_exists = 'overlay'``` if it suits your needs.

Comment: Yes, in the end I upgraded to 1.4 to be able to use if_sheet_exists = 'overlay'